# How to slice array then shuffle it

Tags: php

I have an function that creates an array of words from a string, counts how often each word occurs and then selects the top 21 words.

Trouble I'm having is I then need to shuffle those 21 words. If I try shuffle() my foreach loop will output the number of occurences rather than the word itself.

Can someone show me how to do this? Here is my existing function:

```
$rawstring = implode(" ", $testimonials);

$rawstring = filterBadWords($rawstring);

// get the word=>count array
$words = array_count_values(str_word_count($rawstring, 1));

// sort on the value (word count) in descending order
arsort($words);


// get the top frequent words
$top10words = array_slice($words, 0, 21);
shuffle($top10words);

foreach($top10words as $word => $value) {
    $class = getClass($value);
    echo "<a href=\"#\" id=\"" . $word . "\" class=\"" . $class . "\">" . $word . "</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use

```
function shuffle_assoc( $array ) { 
    $keys = array_keys( $array ); 
    shuffle( $keys ); 
    return array_merge( array_flip( $keys ) , $array ); 
}
```

eg:

```
$top10words = array_slice($words, 0, 21);
$top10words = shuffle_assoc($top10words);

foreach($top10words as $word => $value) {
    $class = getClass($value);
    echo "<a href=\"#\" id=\"" . $word . "\" class=\"" . $class . "\">" . $word . "</a>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mihai but I'm not really sure how this would work with what I already have?